# Web facing application on Kubernetes and AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, coreos, kubernetes

It seems like the best way to deploy a external facing application on Google Cloud would be to create an external load balancer with this line in the service configuration:

`{
...
  "createExternalLoadBalancer": true
...
}`

This doesn't seem to work for AWS. I'm getting the following error when running the service create:

`requested an external service, but no cloud provider supplied`

I know about the PublicIPs setting in services, but that would involve knowing the service's IP in advance so I can set a domain name to it, but so far that doesn't look to be possible if I want to set it up using an external service like AWS ELB.

What's the recommended way of doing this on AWS?

Comment: FWIW if you know the cluster host IP's won't be changing you could use `publicIP` to point to those nodes, then hook a load balancer.  It is the workaround that I am using for now.

Comment: looks like issue 2672 was resolved. Does it work for you now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is still a work in progress.

Please see:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/pull/2672

For a proposal that starts to add support for AWS ELBs to Kubernetes, we're working to get that pull request integrated.

Thanks!